# Creating more than one worksheet through datatable or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, excel, datatable, worksheet

My code is

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#datatableswwarend').DataTable( {
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
              {
                extend: 'excel',
                text: 'Download Report',
                exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible'
                }
              },

              'colvis',
              'copy'
         ],
         columnDefs: [ 
            {
                targets: '_all',
                visible: true
            }]                                               
        });
    });
</script>
```

Above code is my current code, which enables the user to download data from a table saving it as an excel file. Using this current code, is there any way i could create another worksheet, renaming it, and manipulating the data that will be stored in the file?